# But where can I buy it?

Tags: us5024628

I just read all about US5024628 Maternity and Nursing bra patent, but is there a way to find what products are based on this patent?

Comment: Questions about purchasing the product are off topic, but the information about how to find products based on a patent  might prove useful to helping with prior art requests.

Answer (score 2):

Since the USPTO assignment database does not show that the original inventor ever signed over her patent to a company, I would call up or write a letter to the inventor, Mary Sanchez of Tucson AZ. The USPTO database, [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair), has her address and the name and phone number of her patent attorney. After getting past the Capcha screen at PAIR, you can type in the patent number and check the radio button to indicate you are searching by patent number. That will bring up the info on this patent. The tab on the far right is 
Addresses and Attorneys. The Info is there.